# Clarification for include/require relative to calling script

Tags: php

[Documentation](http://cz.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) states:

> Files are included based on the file path given or, if none is given, the include_path specified. If the file isn't found in the include_path, include() will finally check in the calling script's own directory and the current working directory before failing. The include() construct will emit a warning if it cannot find a file; this is different behavior from require(), which will emit a fatal error.

I'm a little confused by the part of the sentence:

`finally check in the calling script's own directory`

**Example of a tree structure:**

- index.php
- libs

  - encryption.php
  - AES.php

**My code:**

`index.php` includes `libs/encryption.php`.

In `encryption.php` is:

```
require 'AES.php'; // <-- should this command end with an error?
```

From what documentation says I would say it should not end with an error but the commands fails in reality.

What is the proper behaviour then?

Thanks!

Comment: `encryption.php` include file `AES.php` whats wrong with that ?

Comment: what's the exact error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The script" in this case refers to the execution script rather than the included module.